# Is it possible to programmatically authorize Facebook AdAccounts to be managed by an App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, ads-api

I am currently developing an app to manage my clients' Facebook AdAccounts. The usual workflow is to, among other things, individually authorize each AdAccount I want my app to have clearance to, by use of the dashboard at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/`. The usual path is you click on your app -> `Settings` -> `Advanced` and scroll down until you find the `Advertising Accounts` panel. Then you click on the top-right button called `Ads API` and use the modal to manually include the Ad Account IDs to which you want to have API permissions.

However, this app is intended to manage dozens or hundreds of Ad Accounts, and it's supposed to manage this **programmatically**, as per the app's requirements. I looked all over the place and couldn't find any endpoints or wrappers in any programming languages to do that and I've been stuck for a few days now... so I was wondering if you guys could help me somehow.

Answer (score 3):

That place you're referring to only applies to apps with 'Development' or 'Basic' access to the API

If you [apply for](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) and receive 'Standard' access, that dialog isn't necesssary, and your app can make API calls on behalf of any user who grants your app the `ads_management` permission

I.e once a user grants your app access to their accounts, you use their access token to access any accounts they are able to manage, on their behalf; it's only in the lower access levels of the API you need to provide a fixed list of Ad Accounts you'll be managing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Business Manager APIs. They're intended for the use case you mentioned (managing other accounts).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/v2.6

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I did some digging into the BusinessManager APIs but got absolutely nowhere; all of them returned a `Unknown path components` error. 

For example, the POST request 

`curl -F "name=Good App Name" -F "vertical=ADVERTISING" -F "primary_page=xxxx" -F "timezone_id=25" -F "access_token=xxxxx" "https://graph.facebook.com/2.6/xxxxx/businesses"`

returned 

`"Unknown path components: \/xxxxx\/businesses"`